# Python cv2 does not write video

Tags: python, opencv

Hi i am trying to break a long video down into smaller videos. I got some code of the internet but when I run it it does not write the video what is wrong with my code?
I am not getting any errors.

```
import cv2
count = 0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    vidPath = 'VideoNietBewerkt.mp4'
    shotsPath = '/videos/%d.avi' % count
    segRange = [(0,1000),(1000,2000),(2000,3000)] # a list of starting/ending frame indices pairs

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidPath)
    fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    fourcc = int(cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')) # XVID codecs

    for idx,(begFidx,endFidx) in enumerate(segRange):
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(shotsPath,fourcc,fps,size)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,begFidx)
        ret = True # has frame returned
        while(cap.isOpened() and ret and writer.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            frame_number = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) - 1
            if frame_number < endFidx:
                writer.write(frame)
            else:
                break
        writer.release()
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a problem with the codec (at least for me) and with the output filename, which is not updated outside the loop.

I made some changes for working on my machine, try this out with a short movie, there are few comments in the code itself.

This worked for me:

```
import cv2
vidPath = 'movie.mp4'
segRange = [(0,30),(30,60),(60,90)] # <-- to fit my sample movie

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidPath)
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
fourcc = int(cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'jpeg')) # <-- I had to change the codec

for idx,(begFidx,endFidx) in enumerate(segRange):
    shotsPath = f'movie_{str(idx)}.avi' # <-- update filename here, use idx for naming the output file
    print(f'saving file: {shotsPath}')

    writer = cv2.VideoWriter() # <-- instantiate the writer this way
    writer.open(shotsPath, fourcc, fps, size) # <-- open the writer
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, begFidx)

    while(cap.isOpened() and writer.isOpened()): # removed and ret
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame_number = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) - 1
        if frame_number < endFidx:
            writer.write(frame)
        else:
            break
    writer.release()
cap.release()
```

Comment: This did not work for me but thanks to your code I did found the solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not closed my cap variable I fixed this by putting everything in the for loop

```
import cv2
vidPath = 'VideoNietBewerkt.mp4'
segRange = [(0,5000),(5000,50000),(50000,100400)] # <-- to fit my sample movie

for idx,(begFidx,endFidx) in enumerate(segRange):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidPath) # <---- Open Cap
    fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    size = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    fourcc = int(cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'jpeg'))
    shotsPath = f'movie_{str(idx)}.avi' # <-- use idx for naming the output file
    print(f'saving file: {shotsPath}')

    writer = cv2.VideoWriter() # <-- instantiate the writer this way
    writer.open(shotsPath, fourcc, fps, size) # <-- open the writer
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, begFidx)

    while(cap.isOpened() and writer.isOpened()): # removed and ret
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame_number = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) - 1
        if frame_number < endFidx:
            writer.write(frame)
        else:
            break

    writer.release()
    cap.release() #<--- Closed Cap
```

Comment: While it is suggested to release the objects, this is not the problem. Try commenting out the line. Try using xvid codec instead of jpeg. Try moving `shotsPath` outside the loop as it was in the OP.